# I cant affordable to buy arcgis.therefore ı want to make a small gis project in Qgis but can I convert shp files( which ı made in qgis) to ARCGSmdb

Tags: arcgis, qgis

can we convert q gis shp files to arcgis mdb? I tried it but not succeed.

or can ı find program may be able to convert shp files to arc mdb?

Answer (score 0):

What you call an `mdb` is usually known as a `file geodatabase` and is a proprietary ESRI file format, QGis can read and write them via the [GDAL library](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/filegdb.html). I think that this will only work if you are on a Windows machine as it doesn't show up on my Linux box.